# Can I force the suffix used by the Typescript Compiler for a class import

Tags: typescript, transpiler, typescript3.0

If we have a typescript import like so:

```js
import {Core} from "./libs/Core";
```

which transpiles to this:

```js
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const Core_1 = require("./libs/Core");
```

is there a way I can force the compiler to use a different suffix than "_1" for the "Core_1" variable?

What I'd like to be able to do is have the compiler use a random number instead of 1 (which could be 7) like so:

```js
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const Core_7 = require("./libs/Core");
```

In my use case I want to be able to load a copy of a script with potentially the same files, but an upgraded version, of the script in the same browser window. The old script would essentially shut itself down, but the new script wouldn't have any variable or namespace collisions.

Comment: No there isn't, unless you are willing to modify the compiler.. Is there a reason you want to change this?

Comment: I added my use case in the body. But ultimately: I want to be able to load a copy of a script with potentially the same files, but an upgraded version, of the script in the same browser window. The old script would essentially shut itself down, but the new script wouldn't have any variable or namespace collisions.

Comment: Isn't this the problem that [hot module replacement](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/hot-module-replacement/) solved?

Comment: @spender for a dev environment, yes. I'm looking to do this in a production environment to push updates to software without any special web servers etc., and without reloading the page. May look under the hood of HMR to see if something from the approach can be used in my case. I've established that dynamic unloading of javascript scripts is not possible, so need to be able to add a script without collision and hopefully not make my dev environment/setup extremely complicated.

Comment: But `Core_1` is just a local variable... this seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).